# How to loop string()() array in vb.net to append a string?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `errorarray()() as String` and this array has the following format

```
Errorarray(0)
             (0) 6869
             (1) textA
          (1)
             (0) 1234
             (1) textB
          (2)
             (0) 3456
             (1)
```

I need to append one string along with all the `array(1)` items. For example, `textB+mystring` if it's not empty.

How will achieve this?

Comment: `Errorarray(1)(1) &= "mystring"` ?

Comment: @markl How will I iterate through array items? Can you provide one example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to grab "textA", "textB", etc...where all those values are not blank?

If so, you could do something like:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Errorarray = {
        ({"6869", "textA"}),
        ({"1234", "textB"}),
        ({"3456", ""})
    }

    Dim all1s As String = ""
    For y As Integer = 0 To Errorarray.GetUpperBound(0)
        If Errorarray(y)(1) <> "" Then
            all1s = all1s & If(all1s = "", "", "+") & Errorarray(y)(1)
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(all1s)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Resulting in:

```
textA+textB
```

Comment: One more thing. So once I append my string I can update my Errorarray(y)(1) with that newly updated string right?

Comment: Sure...you can put your new value back in.  Not sure exactly what you're looking for there, though.  Can you post an "after" array just like in your original post to show how it should look when we're done?

Comment: I checked through code and it's working. So accepting ur answer :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim arr() As String = Errorarray(1)
For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
     If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(arr(i)) Then
         arr(i) &= "mystring"
     End If
Next

Console.WriteLine(Errorarray(1)(1)) ' Will produce "textBmystring"
```